# Calling Django function from html

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-views

I am having trouble running a function in the view from an html button but the code seems to be right so if anyone knows what I am missing I would greatly appreciate it. The ultimate goal is to start a celery task so if there is a better way to do that please let me know.

template.html:

```
<form action="{% url 'save' pk=project.id %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <button id="saveChanges" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Save</button>
        </form>
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ....
    url(r'^manage/save(?P<pk>\d+)/$', 'myapp.views.Save', name="save"),
    ....)
```

views.py

```
def Save(request, pk):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       project = Project.objects.get(id = pk)
       ....
       task.delay(project.id)
   return HttpResponse('OK', status=200)
```

Comment: @Daniel nothing at the moment. I will know when it working though when the celery terminal adds the task

Comment: Does the log show that `manage/save` was called with a `POST`? Was it a 200-class (okay) or 500-class (error) status?

Comment: `HttpResonse` should be `HttpResponse`

Comment: @shavenwarthog I'm not sure how to check the log

Comment: @karthikr sorry, that was just a typo when I wrote it in the question

Comment: 1. Check the generated HTML is correct (view source in your browser). 2. Check the POST sends what you expect (use browser debugger to see network conversation). 3. Check Django goes to the right view (print something, should show up in log) 4. Check view gives correct response, no errors in server log.

Comment: @Spacedman it doesn't look like a post is made in the network log

Comment: what exactly do you mean by 'trouble?'. The form submits, it doesn't, it goes to the wrong view? In any case, This doesn't work? "{% url save project.id %}"

Answer (score 0):

@DoctorWizard run your server with `manage.py runserver` -- the log will be on the same terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Your url pattern is using named groups which will pass keyword arguments to the view. Your view is only accepting positional arguments.

Either change the URL pattern to `r'^manage/save(\d+)/$'` (did you want a slash after `save`?)

OR

Change the view arguments to `def Save(request, pk=None):` or `def Save(request, **kwargs):` and pull `pk` from `kwargs`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/urls/#named-groups